# VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxxx.visualstudio.com

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a web app running in Azure within the context of a Managed Identity.  This managed identity has been made an owner of the Azure DevOps project.  I am attempting to connect to the Azure DevOps API and retrieve list of releases.  When working with a PAT token, all is well.  When this thing is deployed to WebApp, I am getting the error in question.
Managed Identity appears to be correctly configured on the WebApp, as it connects to various Azure resources w/o issues.

What am I missing? This is a greenfield projects, so everything is latest. Using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.* v19.225.1 nuget packages

```
    public class VssCredentialProvider : IVssCredentialProvider
{
    private readonly IRuntimeEnvironmentQuery _runtime;
    private readonly IAppLogger _logger;
    private const string AdoAppClientId = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default";

    public VssCredentialProvider(IRuntimeEnvironmentQuery runtime, IAppLogger logger)
    {
        _runtime = runtime;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<VssCredentials> GetVssCredentials()
    {
        if (_runtime.IsDevelopment)
        {
            var vsoId = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VSO_ID")!;
            var vsoToken = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VSO_PAT")!;

            return new VssCredentials(new VssBasicCredential(vsoId, vsoToken));
        }

        var tokenObject = await new DefaultAzureCredential()
            .GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { $"{AdoAppClientId}/.default" }));

        await _logger.LogAsync($"Retrieved ADO API token expiring on {tokenObject.ExpiresOn}");

        return new VssCredentials(new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(tokenObject.Token));
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used this API yet, but the scope `"499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default/.default"` has `/.default` twice which seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default" }), CancellationToken.None);` As mentioned by mbd, the scope is `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default/.default` in your scripts.

You can also refer to this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/ServicePrincipalsSamples/ClientLibsNET/2-ConsoleApp-ManagedIdentity/Program.cs).